# an example of extending res.partner with delegation

Tags: odoo-14

I could only find res.users

Are there any other examples ?

By "with delegation" I mean with `_inherits`, not with `_inherit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find only `res.users` in all Odoo community code as delegation inheritance from  `res.partner`

You can check the [GitHub example](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Odoo-14-Development-Cookbook-Fourth-Edition/blob/master/Chapter04/13_inheritance_delegation/my_library/models/library_book.py#L135) for delegation inheritance from  `res.partner`

Comment: the exmple on Github seems what I needed, indeed

But I run into an error about a "create_company" missing method

Maybe because I hadn't used the required=True argument in the partner_id field ?

Oh well, I moved to _injerit by now

Thanks anyway, appreciated